# Using List Blobs is it possible to get blob size instead of blob length?

Tags: rest, azure-storage

I'm using the List Blob function with the REST API, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad) this previously gave you blob size, for example 2mb, but now gives you blob length, 3000 characters. Is it possible to revert to the earlier version and retrive blob size instead?

I've tried using the additional filters, and looking at the problem using different services like cloudshell, but no luck so far. Hoping there might be a simple answer i'm overlooking like using a different api-version?

Currently the code request i'm sending to the API is just:

```
https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?restype=container&comp=list&x-ms-version=2018-03-28
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the link to the REST API documentation and your code.

Comment: Size of the blob should be in `Content-Length` element under `Properties`. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: Hi, @howlieT Are you not getting `Content-length` like this https://i.imgur.com/bTgQtSe.png.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri @ Vebkatesan I am seeing that, but wondering if it's possible to get it as blob size expressed in MB/KB instead of content length?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You will need to do the conversion yourself. REST API will return you a number which is the size of blob in bytes.

Comment: Turns out I was misreading it, I can work with size in bytes and clean it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am seeing that, but wondering if it's possible to get it as blob size expressed in MB/KB instead of content length?

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, `REST API` will return with size in bytes. If you need to get in kb or mb of blob content you can use python SDK.

Here is the code to get the blob size in mb or kb.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


connection_string = "your-storage-connection-string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test")

# List the blobs in the container
blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    blob_size_bytes = blob_properties.size
    blob_size_kb = blob_size_bytes / 1000
    blob_size_mb = blob_size_bytes / 1000000
    print("Blob name: {}, size: {} bytes, {} KB, {} MB".format(blob.name, blob_size_bytes, blob_size_kb, blob_size_mb))
```

**Output:**

```
Blob name: demo.csv, size: 2265 bytes, 2.265 KB, 0.002265 MB
Blob name: xmlfile.xml, size: 4548 bytes, 4.548 KB, 0.004548 MB
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List blobs with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list-python)

Comment: Turns out I was misreading size in bytes as length in characters, thank you!